# LINQ Query that is able to identity a Row in a Junction Table with two variables - How to do it?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I use c#, linq and EF4.

I need help to write a LINQ query that is able to identify a Row in a DataBase using two variables for a Composite PRIMARY KEY.

Here tables in my DataBase represented in my Conceptual Model:

DataBase Tables:

```
CmsContents
CmsCategories
CmsRelatedCategories (Pure Juction Table)
```

Entity Type:

```
CmsContent
CmsCategory
```

Entyt Set:

```
CmsContents
CmsCategories
```

I have some Navigational Properties:

```
for CmsContents --> CmsCategories --> Return Collection of Cms CmsCategory
for CmsCategories --> CmsContents --> Return Collection of Cms CmsContents
```

Data in DataBase for the Junction Table is presented:

```
CategoryId     ContentId
7              1
7              2
9              2
```

I need to identify a SINGLE OBJECT in the Pure Junction Table using two variables CategoryId and ContentId example:

```
CategoryId     ContentId
9              2
```

At the moment I use this code to retrieve a single Object but does not work properly.

```
CmsContent myContentObj = (CmsContent)context.CmsContents.Where(x => x.ContentId == myContentId);
```

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: "Doesn't work" isn't an adequate description of an error. What is your problem, and what do you want? An instance of CmsCategory or an instance of CmsContent?

Comment: hi, i would like an instance of CmsContent

Comment: If you want to retrieve a single row, both id's must be known, right?
You're now only testing for contentid, not for catagoryid.

Comment: correct, i know both contentid and catagoryid and I need to use theme together to identify a specific row

Comment: @GibboK: are you sure? What is the PK of the table CmsContents? Also, see my answer and try it, please.

Comment: You can't indentify and retireve single row from junction table in your code because this is not represented by entity. It is relation.

Comment: Thanks Daniel for you answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
CmsContent myContentObj = context.CmsContents.Where(x => x.ContentId == myContentId).FirstOrDefault();
```

I assumed that `ContentId` is the complete primary key for the CmsContent table. This assumption should be correct, because otherwise your mapping table wouldn't make any sense.

Explanation:
Your query *doesn't work*, because `where` returns an `IEnumerable<CmsContent>`, not a single instance. That's what `FirstOrDefault` is for: It returns the first found element or `null` (more precisely `default(CmsContent)`), if no elements where found with the specified content id.